# Проводник каталогов в Java

Tags: java

Хочу сделать аналог виндового "Проводника" - приложение, которое отображает все логические диски на компьютере, с возможностью зайти на диск, посмотреть каталоги, файлы в них и т.д. Я так понял что можно сделать средствами JTree, но в виде "дерева" не очень удобно, хотелось бы чтобы получилось именно как в винде - плитки.
Можно ли это как то сделать? Может есть примеры?